# web.config - Ignore rewrite for specific folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, wordpress, url-rewriting, web-config

The root is a WordPress site. I need to ignore URL rewrite for a folder "app", as I hosted a virtual directory .NET App on that folder.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/app
```

URL Rewrite rules in web.config works partially. If the URL link to a static file or folder in the .NET app, it works. If the URL link to a routed url, it fails. How to fix?

For example this URL:

```
mywebsite.com/app/Login
```

shoud be routed to

```
mywebsite.com/app/Login.aspx
```

but, it is captured by WordPress and display a 404 not found error.

if the URL is entered as this, then it runs ok:

```
mywebsite.com/app/Login.aspx
```

Here is the web.config at root site (wordpress)

```
<rule name="WordPress: http://www.mywebsite.com" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
<match url="*"/>
<conditions>
<add input="{R:0}" pattern="^/app" negate="true" />
<add input="{R:0}" pattern="^/app/(.*)$" negate="true" />
<add input="{R:0}" pattern="^app/(.*)$" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
</rule>
```

This is the code for URL routing in the .NET App

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("login", "login", "~/login.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using this line:

```
<add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="*/app" negate="true"/>
```

There is a nice [reference by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference) that explains in detail how these rules work.